# JComboBox - Array list setting selected item

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, combobox, selection

Hi guys Im having a little trouble with setting the selected item of my combobox

I am currently reading a file which contains an object of a person

I have a combo box which is made by using an array list with 3 names inside of it

I am wanting to read the file get the current name in the file of the person and set that name to my combo box field

heres what I have so far:

```
for(Person p : personList){
    if(p.getName() == personList.toString()){
     personComboBox.setSelectedItem(p.getName());
    }
}
```

I have already managed to read through the file, I'm just wanting to update my selected item in my combo box

Comment: First don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`. Second I'm not sure that you want to compare the name with the String representaion of your list. That makes no sense.

Comment: my personList is of type Person

Comment: Do you know what `personList.toString()` does? I suggest you to print this to see what it outputs.

Comment: Can we see the Person class please.

Comment: ok how do i get the value of whatever is in my arraylist at that index?

Comment: EDITED my question, I change personComboBox.setitem() my mistake, however it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

1 - personList is an array, not an item.
2 - Never use == to compare Strings! Prefer .equals().

What you should be doing is somethink like this:

```
String personInTheFile = "Fubar Rabuf";
for(int i=0; i<personComboBox.getItemCount(); i++){
    Person p = personComboBox.getItemAt(i);
    if(personInTheFile.equals(p.toString())){
        personComboBox.setSelectedIndex(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: My arraylist is holding the values of my combobox, and person is used to check if the value of that array is equal to the person object that I have pulled from my file

Comment: But how? In your file, you have just one person, not a list of persons, right? The array can have many "People" inside, but you are comparing it to just one "People". This will never return true, even because you are comparing using ==, that compares the memory address and not the content. In the code above, i explained a simple way to achieve what you want (if i understood your doubt correctly).